# SMTP Yahoo IPv6 Error getsockaddrarg() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, smtp, yahoo

When i set outgoing IP for gmail SMTP (Ipv6) , i login and send email with no issues

But when i try to use Yahoo SMTP (using ipv6) i got error :

**error :** `TypeError: getsockaddrarg() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)`

Working script :

```
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587,source_address=('2a04:5201:1::1c2',0,0,0))
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login('email@gmail.com', 'pwd')
```

Not working script :

```
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587,source_address=('2a04:5201:1::1c2',0,0,0))
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login('email@yahoo.com', 'pwd')
```

How can i use Yahoo SMTP with outgoing IP IPv6 ?